# Не дублицировать адрес сайта в a тэге

Tags: html, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Как указать ссылку так, чтобы она отражалась и в текстовом виде как ссылка, и по ней можно было перейти? Но чтобы не надо было 2 раза прописывать адрес, а только 1 раз.

Должен быть такой же результат, но указать site.com надо только в 1 месте.

```
<a href="site.com">site.com</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этого делать не нужно. Это стандарт HTML и это нормально. В href Вы пишите адрес, на какой URL переходить при нажатии по ссылке. Внутри ссылки анкор(текстовое описание ссылки или дублируете адрес ссылки). То есть если Вам нужно чтобы отображался адрес на который переходит пользователь то он получается пишется 2 раза. Это стандарт и это нормально.

Comment: Нет никаких параметров, которые говорят, мол, брать текст тега из `href` или наоборот? Или других тегов?

Comment: Ещё добавлю, что конечно то что Вы пишите возможно сделать используя JavaScript, но этого делать не нужно для описанного Вами случая, поскольку: 1) как описал уже это стандарт; 2) поисковики для правильной индексации могут сработать неверно или даже отнестись к сайту негативно в определённых случаях если Вы подставляете тексты ссылок по JS и берёте их из атрибута href. При этом есть случаи когда возможно что данные о ссылке передаются только 1 раз, но это в случаи если Вы информацию по AJAX подгружаете а далее по JS вставляете в страницу.

Comment: В HTML такого параметра нет, мол добавил что то и <a href="https://ya.ru"></a> автоматически сделает ссылку с подствеченным текстом https://ya.ru При этом как я уже выше написал, такое можно реализовать на JavaScript, при этом Вы получите возможные проблемы которые я описал выше, а сокращения по размеру текста в HTML не получите, поскольку JavaScript не в 2 строчки будет и смысл с ним заморачиваться? Я понимаю если для динамической загрузки - там да. Главное просто поймите что так как Вы пишите никто не делает, поскольку это не предусмотрено стандартом.